Struggling w/ grid detection
I'm currently working with a neuroscience lab and need help coding a behavioral test. Where I'm stuck at is struggling with grid detection for my project. I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to Computer Vision so guidance would be appreciated. Here's an example of the image I'm working with:
Base image
I want to detect the lines in the grid here and have tried various approaches (Hough transform + Canny edge detection, Sobel edge detection, even color-based detection). When I try Hough transform + Canny, here's the result I get:
Result
Basically not very accurate lol. It also classifies some of the silver lining incorrectly and is pretty poor when it comes to trying to detect some of the gridlines that are in the shadows near the top and sides of the image. Here is my code for how I'm implementing it right now:
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('grid_image.png')
gray_img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edges = cv2.Canny(gray_img, 50, 150)

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho=1, theta=np.pi/180, threshold=100, minLineLength=100, maxLineGap=10)

line_img = np.zeros_like(img)

for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(line_img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)

# combine images
result = cv2.addWeighted(img, 0.8, line_img, 1, 0)

# Display the result
cv2.imshow('Grid Detection', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

I'm a little bit lost and would like some guidance on what I can do to improve/change my approach. Please let me know, any help would be appreciated.

You know it's a grid.  Once you have a few lines, you can generate the grid analytically, right?

Would you mind elaborating more on this? My problem right now is that I'm not getting enough lines to generate the grid analytically (at least not in a way to do it consistently)

Sure you are.  You have segments of 10 vertical lines and 10 horizontal lines.  It depends on what you need, of course, but that's enough to establish most of the grid.

From the picture, it seems that you have 24 "cells" across the width of the grid, and 14 across the height. If you manage to estimate the corners of the grid, its height and width, you might approximate the position of each cell.

single-image fence removal using CNN: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8933392 -- https://www.reddit.com/r/interestingasfuck/comments/jmsk9q/this_ai_is_trained_to_remove_viewing_obstructions/

I tried to do better preprocessing of the image before doing HoughLines, which include removing noise areas like rat and edge regions. I think with the noises in the image, it will be difficult to draw entire grid area. You can see sample code and result below.
import cv2
import numpy as np

THRESHOLD = 100 #Threshold to get grid lines.

img = cv2.imread('base.png')
gray_img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#convert to gray

#Crop image to get the good grid area, remove other noises like rat and edges.
cropped_image = np.ones_like(gray_img)*255
cropped_image[223:568,635:1170]=gray_img[223:568,635:1170]

cv2.imwrite("cropped_image.jpg",cropped_image)

#Threshold to get the grid
cropped_image[cropped_image > THRESHOLD] = 255
cropped_image[cropped_image < 255] = 0
cropped_image = (255-cropped_image)
#Morphology to avoid noises
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
cropped_image = cv2.morphologyEx(cropped_image, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

cv2.imwrite("grid_image.jpg",cropped_image)

#Do hough transform to get lines of grid area.
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(cropped_image, rho=1, theta=np.pi/180, threshold=225, minLineLength=100, maxLineGap=20)
line_img = np.zeros_like(img)

#Draw Line on actual image.
for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imwrite("result_image.jpg",img)


